# File name doesnt appear when uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

I have a form and I have a part where I upload images, but when I upload an image, her name does not appear on the label, I found a code that made it work in parts because it does not show only the image name and yes "C: \ fakepath \ image name", in short, I just want the image name, thanks!

***Form:***

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@var) do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true, label: "Add an iamge" %>
```

***JS which show "C: \ fakepath \ image name":***

```
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.custom-file-input').change(function(){
    $('.custom-file-label').text(this.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: .original_filename?  Do .inspect on the file you receive from the params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// When working with turbolinks stop moshing your code inside of turbolinks:load and ready handlers. 
// Write delegated event handlers instead which are idempotent by design.
$(document).on('change', '.custom-file-input', function(e) { 
  // split file path by back or forward slashes
  let path = this.value.split(/^.*[\\\/]/);
  this.labels[0].innerText = path.slice(-1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <label for="custom_file_input">Filename goes here</label>
  <input name="custom_file_input" id="custom_file_input" class="custom-file-input" type="file"/>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i still have a question, if i add more than one file, would i have to show the name of all of them? and how could i do it?

Comment: `this.files` will give you list of the files that you can iterate through. This is really a separate question though and should be asked as such. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList